# What happens when calling the str.erase with "pos" equal to the string's length?

Tags: c++

The docs for the string [erase(pos,len)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) function doesn't specify very clearly what exactly happens if `pos` happens to be "one-past-end" of the string. It only hints that this is not forbidden, but not mentioning specifically what this special case means.

Indeed, `str.erase(str.size())` does NOT throw an exception.

What is really supposed happen in this case? This seems not mentioned anywhere explicitly.

Comment: Please decrease the size of the title and put the question details into the question text. May even make the question more understandable.

Comment: These are not "the docs" for anything. Prefer http://cppreference.com or [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that "spacial case".
Same as `str.erase(0,0);` will not do anything. `str.erase(str.size());` is telling it to delete all chars form the end to the end. which erase nothing.

> **C++11 §21.4.6.5:** 
>   “Effects: Determines the effective length `xlen` of the string to be removed as the smaller of `n` and `size() - pos`. The function then replaces the string controlled by `*this` with a string of length `size() - xlen` whose first `pos` elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string controlled by `*this`, and whose remaining elements are a copy of the elements of the original string controlled by `*this` beginning at position `pos + xlen`.”

Comment: +1 for first correct answer. i misinterpreted the question and provided an incorrect answer. :-( deleted...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf no wonder at the misunderstanding, because someone edited the title into something totally different than what I intended. fixed

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. So is this "one-past-end" just something that is just "well-known" so the docs don't even have to bother mentioning this case? This "one-past-end" indeed looks like a pretty prevalent concept in the C++ world...

Answer (score 2):

It's written in your link that

> If pos is greater than the string length, an out_of_range exception is thrown.

I think that answers the question.

Comment: No, it doesn't because in that case pos is not greater than string length, but EQUAL to it.

Comment: @user2015453 `pos` starts at zero so if `pos` equals the size, it is one past the end.

Comment: @user2015453 The string length *doesn't not count* the terminator character.